# Find cell with conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have conditionally formatted a worksheet to change the color of cells if values are in error. This is for data validation where the user may cut and paste large amounts of data into the worksheet at once.

I want to write a macro (which I will link to a button) to find and go to the first cell with conditional formatting, then the next, etc. So far, no luck. If this is ultimately not possible, I may just remove conditional formatting and have a macro change cell color so that it can be more easily detected with VBA.

I can detect if there is any conditional formatting with

If ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> 16777215

but am having trouble putting it into a find sub.

To be more specific, columns A - AF have values and are formatted red if they do not meet conditions. I'd like a duplicate of the find button but for conditional formatting. Does anyone have any suggestions. I've seen similar questions but they seem to be asking for counts or totals and that's not really what I need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use the [macros] tag for Excel/VBA macro questions. Its tag info specifically says, `*Not for MS-OFFICE / VBA / macro languages. Use the respective tags instead.*`

Comment: Thanks Alex, I apologize and will not include that as a tag in future.

Comment: @Matthew Ingle...dumb question but can't you just find them by looking at the sheet, isn't that what the conditional formatting is for? NOW, if you want to put all those cells into an array, then you may need help.

Comment: I know what you're saying and @ChrisB I did know about that function. It's kind of frustrating because I can do these things, but this sheet is used by various users throughout the company and in different time zones, countries, etc. The idea is to make this all transparent. I think I'm just going to use a macro to change the color so that it can then be found. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that returns an array of cell address that have been conditionally formatted with light red background. Edit to suit your purpose.

```
Public Function FindConditionals() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cCell As Range, cntr As Integer
    Dim formattedCells(100) As Variant ' I would used the number of cells in used range here
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    cntr = 1

    For Each cCell In ws.UsedRange
        If cCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then  ' put your own color in
            formattedCells(cntr) = cCell.Address
            cntr = cntr + 1
        End If
    Next cCell
    FindConditionals = formattedCells
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Go To Special" feature in Excel.

On the Home ribbon, click Find and Select > Go To Special.

Then select the option for Conditional Formats.  Click OK and all cells with conditional formats will be selected.